# How to run H2 database in multithreaded way?

Tags: java, multithreading, h2

I am using H2 db (in memory mode with Java) and I have hit a roadblock. I have realized that if I have multiple threads in Java, each thread running a stored proc in H2, at H2 level everything is running in sequence. In other words, although my Java client is multi-threaded, H2 is not.

Now, I can see some people online having commented that H2 could be run in multi-threaded mode. But I could not find some concrete steps / documentation / tutorial to make that happen. Could someone help me please?

There are two concrete answers that I am looking for

1. Can H2 run in multi-threaded way, from a multi-threaded Java client?
2. If so can someone point me to some material?

---

I have read the following links:

1. https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEOT-2832
2. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/VoE3AU7mSuM
3. http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html

I know that `MULTI_THREADED=1` is supposed to make H2 run in multi-threaded way. However, I just don't seem to find someone who says that it worked for him/her. Or someone who has shared the steps of how / where to set `MULTI_THREADED=1`.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Please don't edit and add useless stuff. On SO, no one likes text that isn't related to the question/answer, so remove things like "Thanks for help", "Thanks in advance", "Hope this helps", ...

Comment: Hi, I have been brought up to be polite, particularly in public. If you don't mind, I would like to continue to thank people for any help that they render. Regards.

Comment: Please read the site's help page / meta.stackoverflow.com to see that this site doesn't want those stuff here. I don't mind, but please don't mind if people with >2k rep remove those lines from your questions

Comment: You add the "MULTI_THREADED=1" flag to the end of the JDBC URL.  Like this:

jdbc:h2:file:///C:/path/to/h2/db;WRITE_DELAY=0;AUTOCOMMIT=ON;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE;MULTI_THREADED=1

This example is from https://github.com/Norconex/collector-filesystem/issues/28

Answer (score -4):

H2 with multithreaded statement processing is currently "experimental" and should not be used - if you had done at least [basic research](http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html) you would've discovered this very fact. You can enable it via the `MULTI_THREADED` option but you wont be able to use MVCC.
I think [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/VoE3AU7mSuM) has some more info on the option

Comment: Perhaps this change in the last years. See the multithreading section here:http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html

Comment: -1 for being condescending. This was completely uncalled for. 
That being said, this information might have been up to date as of 2014, but is no longer valid in 2017 with version 1.4. You can now use MVCC and MULTI_TREADED together using the default storage engine.